# Angular UI-router resolving get promise causes post request to become null

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with Ui-router using angular v1.3.15 and ui-router v0.2.8. I have set up routing with nested states and i am resolving promises to load views with data, so far so good. 
My problem comes when I am resolving a promise to show previously saved "work" and trying to add new "work" via POST request i get error: "work can not be null". The strange thing is that when I do not resolve promise of GET to show prevous "work" posts my POST is working as expected (saving the data that is).

I resolve promises to retrieve data to other views and in those views I can do PUT requests without a problem, I do not understand where I am going wrong. Allthough I am new to Angular and might be missing something really simple...

My app.js;
(the first state 'home.edit' gets att the current application and this is working fine, my second state is getting all the 'work', the get works fine)

```
  .state("home.edit",
        {
            url: "/applications/edit/:applicationId",
            templateUrl: "app/applicationEdit/applicationEdit.html",
            controller: "applicationEditCtrl as vm",
            resolve:
                {
                applicationEditResource: "applicationEditResource",

                application: function (applicationEditResource, $stateParams)
                {
                    var applicationId = $stateParams.applicationId;

                    return applicationEditResource.get(
                        { applicationId: applicationId }).$promise;
                },


                }

        })
        .state("home.edit.work", {
            url: "/Work",
            templateUrl: "app/applicationEdit/applicationEditWork.html",
            controller: "workEditCtrl as vm",
            resolve:
                {
                    workEditResource: "workEditResource",

                    work: function (workEditResource) {


                        return workEditResource.get( ).$promise;

                    }

                },


        })
```

My workEditResource;

return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "api/works/:applicationId", null,

```
      {
          'get':
         {
             isArray: true,
             method: 'GET',
             headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token }
         },
          'save': {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token }
          }
      });

}
```

My workEditCtrl;

```
.controller("workEditCtrl",
            ["application",
               "work",
                "workEditResource",
                workEditCtrl]);

function workEditCtrl(application, work, workEditResource) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.fail = '';
    vm.message = '';
    vm.work = work;
    vm.application = application;
    vm.work.applicationId = vm.application.applicationId;


    if (vm.work && vm.application.applicationId) {
        vm.title = "Hantera arbete " + vm.application.applicationId
    }



    //sparar nytt arbete med ansökans ID
    vm.submit = function () {
        vm.fail = '';
        vm.message = '';
        workEditResource.save(vm.work,
                function(data){
                    vm.message = "Nytt arbete sparat"
                }),
        function (response) {

            vm.fail = "Formuläret är inte korrekt ifyllt, var vänlig kontrollera uppgifterna och försök igen.";
        };
    }
}
```

}());

My API controller;

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Work work)
    {
        try
        {
            if (work == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Work can not be null");
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var workRepository = new Models.WorkRepository();
            var newWork = workRepository.Save(work);
            if (newWork == null)
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            return Created<Work>(Request.RequestUri + newWork.WorkId.ToString(), newWork);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

    }
```

Would much appreciate any hints as to what I am missing :)

Comment: Can you run the problematic function in Chrome and monitor the network traffic using the dev tools, to see what "work" object the data posted to the server contains?

Comment: I have after your reply and it contains an array of all 'work' posts, so the assumption that the $resource is confused seems correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A POST is intended to create a new record, and this appears to be the way you are using it, however when resolving the `work` to a previous record, what you are passing to `workEditResource.save` is an existing record, rather than a new one.

I *suspect* that the $resource handler is getting confused by the ID provided in the work object, so trying to POST to the PUT URL for that work ID, rather than POSTing to the URL for creating a new record.

**EDIT:** To resolve this, you should use separate variables in your controller for the two - maybe `vm.previousWork` for the array of old work for viewing, and `vm.work` for the new work you're creating.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right in that the $resource is getting confused however a PUT request did not do the trick in solving it.

Comment: @Lisa Are you trying to update or create a record when you load a previous "work"?

Comment: I only load prevoius work to view then in a table above input form. I use the applicationId to match this with application (on to which a 'work' is aaaociated) So what I am trying to do is load the associated 'work' posts to one specific application for viewing and still have the possibility of adding new 'work' post associated to said application.

Comment: @Lisa I think you should use separate variables in your controller for the two then - vm.previousWork for the array of old work for viewing, and vm.work for the new work you're creating.

Comment: @Lisa I've updated my answer to include that solution, please mark as accepted if you're happy with the resolution.